# Unable to run the command dspmqver command

Tags: ibm-mq

We are facing issue while installing Websphere MQClient v9.0.0.1 on linux machine.at the time of rpm packages installation we are getting below error.

Note: And it is Multi-installation setup,we have a MQClient version 8.0.0.4 in different file system which is Installation1 file system is `/Informatica/app/MQClient`.

Installed packages on server.

```
MQSeriesMan-8.0.0-4.x86_64
MQSeriesGSKit-9.0.0-1.x86_64
MQSeriesGSKit-8.0.0-4.x86_64
MQSeriesSamples-8.0.0-4.x86_64
MQSeriesSDK-9.0.0-1.x86_64
MQSeriesClient-9.0.0-1.x86_64
MQSeriesClient-8.0.0-4.x86_64
MQSeriesSDK-8.0.0-4.x86_64
MQSeriesJava-9.0.0-1.x86_64
MQSeriesMan-9.0.0-1.x86_64
MQSeriesRuntime-8.0.0-4.x86_64
MQSeriesJava-8.0.0-4.x86_64
MQSeriesRuntime-9.0.0-1.x86_64
MQSeriesJRE-9.0.0-1.x86_64
MQSeriesJRE-8.0.0-4.x86_64
MQSeriesSamples-9.0.0-1.x86_64
```

We could see the `libmqmr_r.so` file in below location

`/infaicc/app/MQClient/lib/libmqmr_r.so`

We have set the environment variableby using below command

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/infaicc/app/MQClient/lib64`

but still we are facing same error.

```
rpm -ivh --prefix /infaicc/app/MQClient MQSeriesRuntime-9.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%] 
Updating / installing...    
1:MQSeriesRuntime-8.0.0-0          ################################# [100%]
ERROR: dspmqver: error while loading shared libraries: libmqmcs_r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

rpm -ivh --prefix /infaicc/app/MQClient  MQSeriesClient-9.0.0-7.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                          ################################# [100%] 
Updating / installing...    
1:MQSeriesRuntime-8.0.0-0          ################################# [100%]
ERROR: dspmqver: error while loading shared libraries: libmqmcs_r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

[root@XXXX-as-0037 bin]# ./dspmqver
./dspmqver: error while loading shared libraries: libmqmcs_r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[root@XXXX-as-0037 bin]#
```

1. Please let us know is it mandatory to run this  `crtmqpkg suffix` in multiple installation scenario, if yes kindly confirm from which location I need to run this ( means from `installation1` ) command.
   Our existing setup is working fine without any issue. If we run `crtmqpkg suffix` command is there any impact on my existing version.
2. Before installation should we stop the all existing MQ process?

@Roger/Josh: Thanks for update,we are getting below error while executing ./crtmqpkg 2. kindly help on this issue.

```
[root@xxxx_xxx_xx_ mqclient]# ./crtmqpkg 1
ERROR: Unable to execute "/usr/bin/rpmbuild" - required for packaging.
       Check that you have the "rpm-build" package installed on your system,
       or which ever package provides "rpmbuild" on your Linux distribution.
```

@Josh: we have installed the rpm-build packages and run the ./crtmqpkg 2 command it got succeed but while installing websphere MQ rpm packages getting below error.We followed the given IBM tech-notes still facing error.

```
[root@XXXX_XXX_XX MQClient]# rpm --prefix /infaicc/app/MQClient -ivh /infaicc/app/MQClient_Binary/2/x86_64/MQSeriesRuntime_2-9.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
   1:MQSeriesRuntime_2      ########################################### [100%]
ERROR: Return code "127" from amqicdir for "-i -f", output is:
       /infaicc/app/MQClient/bin/amqicdir: error while loading shared libraries: libmqmcs_r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR:   Return code "127" from crtmqinst for "-p /infaicc/app/MQClient ", output is:
         /infaicc/app/MQClient/bin/crtmqinst: error while loading shared libraries: libmqmcs_r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: Return code "127" from amqicdir for "-s -f", output is:
       /infaicc/app/MQClient/bin/amqicdir: error while loading shared libraries: libmqmcs_r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ERROR: Return code "127" from setmqinst for "-r -p /infaicc/app/MQClient", output is:
       /infaicc/app/MQClient/bin/setmqinst: error while loading shared libraries: libmqmcs_r.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the MQ instructions [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q008640_.htm) or [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q009010_.htm) because I don't see any mention of creating the install package.  Also, you need to set your installation but I don't see anything about it either.

Comment: Thanks for your update. 1) please let us know is it mandatory to run this "crtmqpkg suffix" in multiple installation scenario,if yes kindly confirm from which location i need to run this ( means from installation1 ) command. But existing setup working fine without any issue.if we run "crtmqpkg suffix" command is there any impact on my existing version. 2) Before installation should we stop the all existing( installation1) MQ process?

Comment: Simply follow the instructions in the MQ Knowledge Center - those links I gave above.

Comment: Thanks for update,we are getting below error while executing ./crtmqpkg 2 kindly help on this issue. ``` [root@xxxx_xxx_xx_ mqclient]# ./crtmqpkg 1 ERROR: Unable to execute "/usr/bin/rpmbuild" - required for packaging. Check that you have the "rpm-build" package installed on your system, or which ever package provides "rpmbuild" on your Linux distribution. ```

Answer (score 0):

As Roger pointed out the following IBM MQ Knowledge Center page provided details: [IBM MQ 9.0.x>IBM MQ>Installing and uninstalling>Installing and uninstalling IBM MQ on Linux>Installing IBM MQ on Linux using rpm>Installing IBM MQ server on Linux](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q008640_.htm)

First this page answers your first question:

> **Note**
>
> ---
>
> The **crtmqpkg** command is required only if this is not the first
>   installation of IBM MQ on the system. If you have earlier versions of
>   IBM MQ installed on your system, then installing the latest version
>   works correctly if you install it in a different location.

Given that it appears you already have MQ v8.0.0.4 installed you will need to perform the required steps to create a MQ v9.0.0.7 set of rpms with a new suffix.

The reason this is required is because you can not install two rpms with the same base package name.  By creating a new RPM with a suffix is giving the rpm a different base name.

Actually running the `crtmqpkg` command will not cause any issues with your existing installation since it is just creating new rpm files on the file system.  When you install it as long as you specify a different installation location it will not cause any problem for your existing installation either.

---

Roger provided the second link to the IBM MQ Knowledge Center page that provides details specific to the MQ client packages: [IBM MQ 9.0.x>IBM MQ>Installing and uninstalling>Installing and uninstalling IBM MQ on Linux>Installing IBM MQ on Linux using rpm>Installing an IBM MQ client on Linux](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q009010_.htm)

> 4. If you have multiple installations on this system, you must run **crtmqpkg** to create a unique set of packages to install on the system:
>
>    a. Enter the following command:
>
>    `./crtmqpkg suffix`
>
>    where suffix is a name of your choosing, that will uniquely identify the installation packages on the system. suffix is not the
>      same as an installation name, although the names can be identical.
>      suffix is limited to 16 characters in the ranges A-Z, a-z, and 0-9.
>
>    b. Set your current directory to the location specified when the
>      **crtmqpkg** command completes. This directory is a sub-directory of /var/tmp/mq_rpms, in which the unique set of packages is created. The
>      packages have the suffix value contained within the filename.

---

Because the installation of the new package is not going into the same location there is No requirement to stop existing IBM MQ processes.